# Default Header and Footer, for All Microsoft Project Views?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I currently add header and footer via File > Print > Page Setup, then tabs "Header" and "Footer".

It seems these header and footer settings differ, however, by the view selected. For example, if I select view "Tracking Gantt", I see the header and footer I added, but if I select view "Task Sheet", I see the default header and footer.

Does Microsoft Project allow specifying a default header and footer, for all views?

Note: I hope to upgrade soon, from Microsoft Project Standard 2010, to Microsoft Project Professional 2013 or 2016, so any notes on whether those support this functionality would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered each view in Project can have its own header and footer.  My suggestion is to create a template (it doesn't even need tasks) and store the "defaults" you  want in that template.  You can add headers/footers for each view, custom calendars, custom fields, etc.  Then use that template to create your new projects.

The header/footers are unchanged in Project 2013 and Project 2016.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the feedback.